# The onclick EventListener not working more than once

Tags: javascript, dom-events

i've made a word finder that would find a word whenever i click button and send input in the prompt.

Now the problem is that my event listener's not working more than once.

Here's my javascript code:

```
const words = []; // /lorem/gi, /ipsum/gi

let makeFindWord = document.getElementById("makeFindWord");
makeFindWord.onclick = () => {
    let input = prompt("Search a word");
    console.log("works");

    let value = new RegExp(input, "gi");
    words.push(value);

    console.log(words);

    findTheWord(words);

    console.log(makeFindWord.onclick);
};

function findTheWord(words) {
    const body = document.body;

    let log = [];

    for (const w of words) {

        loo: do {
            let theWord = w.exec(body.innerHTML);
            if (theWord == null) {
                break loo;
            } else {
                let index = theWord.index;
                let length = theWord[0].length;

                let word = body.innerHTML.substring(index, index + length);
                log.push([theWord, word, index, length]);
            }
        } while (true);

    }


    log.forEach(w => {
        let word = w[1];
        body.innerHTML = String(body.innerHTML).replaceAll(word, `<span style="color: #fe0">${word}</span>`);
    });
}
```

Comment: why are you re-assigning the value here? `makeFindWord = document.getElementById("makeFindWord");`

Comment: Bro/Sis, i added that line in my code as a remedy i found when i was searching my question's answer on google and it did'nt work.
I faced the same problem before and after adding this line=>
makeFindWord = document.getElementById("makeFindWord");

Comment: I've found the problem.
=> words.push(value); is the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**
The problem is that you are manipulating the whole body tag using the DOM innerHTML property. It replaces the button with the id "makeFindWord" also and the Event Listener on that button no longer works because you have replaced the button with id "makeFindWord" with new one using innerHTML.. Its pretty normal thing in JavaScript DOM.

**Solution:**
Wrap the whole body inside an other container (say a div with id "search-container"). Don't forget to place your Button (having id "makeFindWord") outside this container.
Here is the complete working code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="makeFindWord">Button</button>
  <div id="search-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
  const words = []; // /lorem/gi, /ipsum/gi

let makeFindWord = document.getElementById("makeFindWord");
makeFindWord.onclick = () => {
    let input = prompt("Search a word");
    console.log("works");

    let value = new RegExp(input, "gi");
    words.push(value);

    console.log(words);

    findTheWord(words);

    console.log(makeFindWord.onclick);
};

function findTheWord(words) {
    const body = document.getElementById("search-container");

    let log = [];

    for (const w of words) {

        loo: do {
            let theWord = w.exec(body.innerHTML);
            if (theWord == null) {
                break loo;
            } else {
                let index = theWord.index;
                let length = theWord[0].length;

                let word = body.innerHTML.substring(index, index + length);
                log.push([theWord, word, index, length]);
            }
        } while (true);

    }


    log.forEach(w => {
        let word = w[1];
        body.innerHTML = String(body.innerHTML).replaceAll(word, `<span style="color: #fe0">${word}</span>`);
    });
}
</script>
```

I have attached a screenshot showing the working output. Now,
EventListener will work forever.

[image]

Comment: Thanks my friend! You've solved my problem forever. Now i understand why there's everything capsulated in a div in the body instead of simply writing it inside the body whenever i inspect a website

Comment: It is a common practice to make break the website into smaller components like nav bar, sidebar, footer, header, etc. and all these components are wrapped inside div. Div is just a container and by wrapping the different components inside Div make it easy for developer to style page and make interactive with javascript.

Comment: OK friend! 

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line in `makeFindWord.onclick`

```
makeFindWord = document.getElementById("makeFindWord");
```

Comment: Bro/Sis, i added that line in my code as a remedy i found when i was searching my question's answer on google and it did'nt work.
I faced the same problem before and after adding this line=>
makeFindWord = document.getElementById("makeFindWord");